# Why does the Window option in Vector make my video upside down

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, video, vector

I'm trying to follow the **Ian Hubert's tutorial for making Lighstabers in blender.** When I imported my video, when I **change the vector option to window, the video gets flipped.** I tried rotating changing the camera angle etc. but it still doesn't work. https://youtu.be/bVUeRIY1E-M This is the video. The timestamp is at 1:23.

Comment: please attach your blender file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the picture but watching the tutorial can make it more understandable.]

This is the picture but watching the tutorial can make it more understandable.

Comment: Hey, I found the answer to my problem in a video on YouTube. Thanks for trying to help!