# Why does the window option in the vector make my video show upside down?

Tags: vector

I have the exact same question as in the post:

[Why does the Window option in Vector make my video upside down](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266336/why-does-the-window-option-in-vector-make-my-video-upside-down)

The answer there is not an answer, just a statement saying that it had been solved it and had found the answer on youtube, but with no link or explanation on how to solve it.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278881/vfx-video-always-flipped-in-movie-editor?rq=1